# Picking N unique random Enums in Dart

Tags: dart

How can I pick **N unique random enums** in dart?

```
enum Fruits { Apple, Peach, Orange, Mango }

List<Fruits> fruit = Fruits.random(N) // <-- implement this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it eventually with sets as @Alok suggested:

```
import 'dart:math';
List<T> generateRandomList<T>(int N, List<T> list) {
  Set<T> setOfT = {};
  var rnd = Random();
  while (setOfT.length < N) {
    setOfT.add(list[rnd.nextInt(list.length)]);
  }
 return setOfT.toList()..shuffle();
}
```

usage:

```
enum Fruits { Apple, Peach, Orange, Mango }

print(generateRandomList(2, Fruits.values));
```

output:

```
[Fruits.Peach, Fruits.Mango]
```

Answer (score 6):

you can create an extension for enum

```
enum Fruits { Apple, Peach, Orange, Mango }

extension FruitsExt on Fruits {
  static List<Fruits> generateRandomFruits(int n) {
    var rnd = Random();
    return List.generate(n, (i) => Fruits.values[rnd.nextInt(Fruits.values.length)]);
  }

  static List<Fruits> generateRandomUniqueFruits(int n) {
    var list = List<Fruits>.from(Fruits.values)..shuffle();
    return list.take(n).toList();
  }

}
```

and use it like this

```
List<Fruits> fruits = FruitsExt.generateRandomFruits(10);
List<Fruits> fruits = FruitsExt.generateRandomUniqueFruits(3);
```

or use it without extension

```
var rnd = Random();
var list = List.generate(10, (i) => Fruits.values[rnd.nextInt(Fruits.values.length)]);
```

or, as mentioned in comments below by @Irn
you can make them top level functions

```
List<Fruits> generateRandomFruits(int n) {
  var rnd = Random();
  return List.generate(n, (i) => Fruits.values[rnd.nextInt(Fruits.values.length)]);
}

List<Fruits> generateRandomUniqueFruits(int n) {
  var list = List<Fruits>.from(Fruits.values)..shuffle();
  return list.take(n).toList();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't generate random unique fruits. The method RandomUnique returns the first N fruits and shuffles them. It will always generate the same fruits.

Comment: I tried it, If for example N equals 2 than It will return Fruits.apple and Fruits.peach all the time

Comment: @Kevin I think I understood what you mean, you're right, I edited the code, check it

Comment: There is absolutely no advantage in putting these static methods into an `extension`. Just make them top-level functions.

Comment: It's doable but there is absolutely no advantage in putting them as  top-level functions also.

Answer (score 1):

Some user's answers is indeed helping. But if we would consider your option of having only **unique enums**, then we might use some other approach. The approach is basically to use [Set class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.0/dart-core/Set-class.html) to store only the unique data. And we are concerned about getting the final data as **List()**, then convert it using `toList()`

```
import 'dart:math';

enum Fruits { Apple, Peach, Orange, Mango }

void main() {
  // we are initializing our Fruits to be a set to store UNIQUE DATA ONLY
  Set<Fruits> _fruits = {};
  
  // this will go on for the length of Fruits, which is 5 right now
  for(int i=0; i<Fruits.values.length; i++){
    // this will only generate the number till your enum's length
    var index = Random().nextInt(Fruits.values.length);
    _fruits.add(Fruits.values[index]);
  }
  
  // converting it to List finally
  print(_fruits.toList());
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[Fruits.Apple, Fruits.Orange, Fruits.Peach]
```

Comment: Interesting approach. this method doesn't check If a value is already exist inside the set. So sometimes it will generate 4 elements, sometimes 3 elements and sometime 2 elements.

Comment: Yes, set does the work for you. So, you can control the number of times you want to loop for generating random numbers. And `Set` will take care of the rest @Kevin

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all values from the enums.values, then shuffle the list and take an appropriate long sublist of it:

```
enum Fruits { Apple, Peach, Orange, Mango }

void main() {
  List<Fruits> fruit = List.from(Fruits.values);

  for(int i=0;i<3;++i) { 
    fruit.shuffle();
    print(fruit.sublist(0,3));
  } 
}
```

Output:

```
[Fruits.Mango, Fruits.Orange, Fruits.Apple]
[Fruits.Apple, Fruits.Orange, Fruits.Mango]
[Fruits.Orange, Fruits.Apple, Fruits.Peach]
```

Answer (score 0):

A general approach for picking a number of elements from any list (or iterable) uniformly at random would be:

```dart
import "dart:math";
extension<T> on Iterable<T> {
  /// Chooses [count] of the elements of this iterable.
  ///
  /// The elements are chosen at random, with each 
  /// element having an equal chance of being in the 
  /// resulting list.
  /// The returned elements are not in any specific order.
  List<T> choose(int count, [Random random]) {
    var iterator = this.iterator;
    List<T> result = [
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        if (iterator.moveNext())
          iterator.current
        else
          throw StateError("Too few elements")
    ];
    random ??= Random();
    var seenCount = count;
    while (iterator.moveNext()) {
      seenCount++;
      var pos = random.nextInt(seenCount);
      if (pos < count) result[pos] = iterator.current;
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

You can then use it on enums as `var someFruits = Fruites.values.choose(2);`.